# POST data with Ajax application/json, read with ashx file

Tags: .net, json, stringify

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropDownMenu1').change(function () {
            var customer = { contact_email: "s.selcuk@hotmail.com", company_password: "123" };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(customer),
                url: "webServices/apiDeneme.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json"
            });
        });
    });
```

I am sending this customer variable like this way to the apiDeneme.ashx. I put debug poing, request comes to apiDeneme.ashx but this email string variable equals null. ? (below)

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    string email = context.Request.Form["contact_email"];      

    sb.Append("[");
    sb.Append("{");
    sb.Append("\"Sonuc\":\"" + email + "\"}]");

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    context.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    context.Response.End();
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

By the way, another question, is the login process like the one here reliable? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

try below code :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#dropDownMenu1').change(function () {
            var customer = { contact_email: "s.selcuk@hotmail.com", company_password: "123" };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {context : JSON.stringify(customer)},
                url: "webServices/apiDeneme.ashx",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success : function(result) {
                         alert("called");
               }
            });
        });
    });
```

and add [httpost] as shown below:-

```
[HttpPost]
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
}
```

Comment: String email is still null but i could not add a [HttpPost]. Tt gives a syntax error. (means: red underline). Why there is no "Resolve.." help from Visual Studio for this syntax error when i type a [HttpPost]. So as a final, the email value is still null. Is this still null because of the [HttpPost]? If yes, how can i add this [HttpPost]  without any syntax error?